# Ways to connect Arduino / Microcontroller to the Web?

Tags: arduino, microcontroller, ethernet, internet

What are the best ways to connect an Arduino or a microcontroller (PIC...) to Internet/Web. I would like to be able to send and recieve information from the Arduino/PIC to the Web and vice-verse even if there is no WiFi around. Maybe connecting to my phone using Bluetooth and using it's internet data (3G) is a good idea? What I am trying to achieve is Google Search and response from the results using Arduino, everywhere. (Carrying my phone with the 3G around is not a problem since I don't think it's a good idea to connect to the radio cells around and probably illegally get information from the internet? Any suggestions will be helpful.

Comment: Have you tried to google something like "arduino wifi module"?

Answer (score 0):

There are [GSM shields](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Guide/ArduinoGSMShield) for the Arduino, yes. But as far as using it as a hotspot for your phone, most likely not. I doubt you can connect your phone to the internet via the GSM shield because you'd essentially be stealing data from a network provider.

However, some of these shields have a SIM card slot so you can place your SIM card inside the device to connect to a network and you can essentially allow it to have the same functionality as your phone and you could make a hotspot that way. For instance, you can send text messages with the shield or you can connect to the internet with the shield.